# Sending email message with attachment by powershell with a batch file

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file

Hi i'm trying to send email from batch file.bat but I'm getting a list of red errors and rolling really fast and the window close also fast I tried to keep it open by the command

```
cmd /k
```

and it's still open but it won't show any error list.

not that: I'm using Gmail account as smtp and i opened smtp settings and enabled the less secure login option.

finally what to run the bat is that command. cmd execute command :

```
file.bat "mygmail@gmail.com" "mypassword" "D:\test\myFile.txt"
```

file.bat contains :

```
@ECHO OFF
    SET GmailAccount=%~1
    SET GmailPassword=%~2
    SET Attachment=%~3

    CALL :PowerShell
    CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
    Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%' '%GmailAccount%' '%GmailPassword%' '%Attachment%'"
    EXIT

    :PowerShell
    SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
    SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpSendeMail.ps1
    IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

    ECHO $Username      = $args[0]>> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]>> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $Attachment    = $args[2]>> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO                          >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $Username    = $Username                 >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $EmailTo     = "target@mail.com" >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $EmailFrom   = "mygmail@gmail.com" >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $Subject     = "test"           >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $Body        = "test"              >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"          >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body) >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment)                            >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment)                                                    >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)                               >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true                                                                >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword) >> "%PSScript%"
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

please Help me what is the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: for writing an empty line: replace `echo <a lot of spaces>` with `echo/` (plus a lot of spaces, if you insist). You forgot to redirect the last line to the PS-Script. Replace `exit` with `exit /b` to avoid closing the window.

Comment: In addition to very good suggestions by Stephan I suggest to remove `IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"` and on next line `ECHO $Username      = $args[0]>> "%PSScript%"` remove one `>` to create the PowerShell script file with overwriting an already existing file. It does not make sense in my opinion to write a batch file which creates a PowerShell script and executes PowerShell with that script file. Why not writing the PowerShell script and start PowerShell with that script file and the three arguments for the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all : [This is a reminder for how to use less secure applications with google accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605803/can-not-send-mail-using-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-from-vbs-script/28606754#28606754)

***PS-Gmail-Sender.bat***

```bat
@ECHO OFF
REM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605803/can-not-send-mail-using-smtp-gmail-com-port-587-from-vbs-script/28606754#28606754
Title Sending E-Mail with Gmail Less Secure Applications using Powershell and Batch
SET GmailAccount="%~1"
SET GmailPassword="%~2"
SET Attachment="%~3"
REM We write our Powershell script 
CALL :WritePS
REM We execute our Powershell script .PS1 by passing arguments from the command line or a batch file
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "%PSScript%" "%GmailAccount%" "%GmailPassword%" "%Attachment%"
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
pause
EXIT
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:WritePS
SET PSScript=%temp%\temp_SendeMail.ps1
> "%PSScript%" (
    ECHO $Username  = $args[0]
    ECHO $EmailPassword = $args[1]
    ECHO $Attachment= $args[2]
    ECHO $EmailTo = $Username
    ECHO $EmailFrom  = $Username
    ECHO $Subject = "This email was sent from Powershell script into a batch file with Less Secure Application Enabled"   
    ECHO $Body= "Test Email Sending with a script"  
    ECHO $SMTPServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"  
    ECHO $SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body^) 
    ECHO $Attachment  = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($Attachment^)
    ECHO $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($Attachment^)
    ECHO $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587^)
    ECHO $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword^) 
    ECHO $SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage^)
)
Exit /B
REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So with the command line or a batch file we can call it as below :

```
PS-Gmail-Sender.bat "Mygmail_Account@gmail.com" "MyGmail_Password" "D:\test\myFile.txt"
```